# compare string elements in php arrays

Tags: php, arrays

I will explain my problem in one simple example. I have 1 array.

```
$array1 =  array( "Sun" => "1", "Lake Red" => "1", "Tree" => "1" )
```

And I have one word

```
$word = "Lake";
```

I want to check if these word are in this array. I did it in this way.

```
if (isset($array1[$word])) {
    print "This word is in the array.\n\n";
}
```

This code that i already have does not do good job to me, because for the program word LAKE is not the same as LAKE RED... how can i fix these, so if the one of the elements have at least one word from the word, then should be written these:

```
print "This word is in the array.\n\n";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `in_array` to check for values that are **identical** to your search. Eg.

```
$array1 = array("Lake Red", "Sun", "Tree"); //note the " around Lake Red
$word = "Lake";`

if (in_array($word,$array1)) 
{
    print "This word is in the array.\n\n";
}
```

to check by doing `if (isset($array1[$word]))` would require you to implement your array as below, and it will look for keys that are **identical** to your search

```
$array = array(
   "Lake" => "Red",
   "Lake Red" => "1",
   "Boo" => "Foo"
);
```

Or if you want to search for a word in the keys of an associative array

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
for($i=0,$count = count($keys);$i<$count;$i++) {
    if (strpos($word, $keys[$i]) !== false) {
        print "This word is in the array.\n\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

or with a foreach

```
foreach($keys as $key) {
    if (strpos($word, $key) !== false) {
        print "This word is in the array.\n\n";
        break;
    }
}
```

however doing it with a for loop is faster and more optimized. Using `implode`  would have memory problems with large arrays. but if we're to do it, here's how.

```
$keys = array_keys($array);
$long_str = implode(" ",$keys);
if (strpos($word, $long_str) !== false) {
    print "This word is in the array.\n\n";
    break;
}
```

Comment: $array = array(
   "Sun" => "1",
   "Lake Red" => "1",
   "Tree" => "1"
);

My array looks like this, thats why i use isset?

Comment: can i use in array or isset for this kind of array?

Comment: for the second type, you can use isset, however if you array is like in the question, it's of the 1st type and , you need to use in_array

Comment: yes, my array looks like second type. I use isset but that dont do good job for me, cause word Lake does not match with Lake Red

Comment: ok, then to rephrase your question(according to the second type of array you're going to use), You want to search for a word in the keys of an associative array, right?

Comment: caun i do it, without using loops?

Comment: last one with implode is without any loops, however I suggest you to use loops

Comment: it does, however the key needs to be identical to the search parameter in order for isset to work.

Answer (score 0):

- Get various values in the array, appended into a single string separated by space (`" "`), using [implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) function.
- Now simply check for the `$word` sub-string in the combined string obtained in the previous step, using [strpos()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) function.

Try the following:

```
// Get all array elements concatenated as a string
$array1 = array("Lake Red", "Sun", "Tree");
$array1_str = implode(" ", $array1);

// use strpos to check if the $word exists
$word = "Lake";
if (strpos($array1_str, $word) !== false) {
    print "This word is in the array.\n\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$os = array("Mac", "NT", "Irix", "Linux");
if (in_array("Irix", $os)) {
    echo "Got Irix";
}
```

Hi, I recommend you to use something like that

Answer (score 0):

Loop through array with foreach and compare each value with $word

```
$array1 = array(Lake Red, "Sun", "Tree");
$word = "Lake"
foreach($array1 as $w){
if($w==$word){
 print "This word is in the array.\n\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think using implode is the best solution who someone answered before. Anyways, I did this function which also works:

```
$array = array("Lake Red", "Sun", "Tree");

function in_array_word($string, $array){
    foreach($array as $index){
        // Check if the current word we're looping is exact to what we look for.
        if(strcmp($index, $string) == 0){
            return true;
        }else if(strpos($index, " ") !== FALSE){
            // If is not the same, check if there are two or more words.
            $words = explode(" ", $index);
            foreach($words as $word){
                if(strcmp(trim($word), $string) == 0){
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return false;
}

var_dump(in_array_word("Lake Red", $array));
var_dump(in_array_word("Lake", $array));
var_dump(in_array_word("Red", $array));
var_dump(in_array_word("Moon", $array));
var_dump(in_array_word("Blue", $array));
var_dump(in_array_word("Tree", $array));

// If we have some spaces mistach will also work for this:
$array2 = array("Lake  Red", "Sun", "Tree");
var_dump(in_array_word("Lake", $array2));

// But not for:
var_dump(in_array_word("Lake Red", $array2));
```

Answer (score 0):

As answered previously [Madhur Bhaiya](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2469308/madhur-bhaiya) you need to get keys of array in string and find word in string. I added lower string and searched word for case insensitive:

```
$array1 =  array( "Sun" => "1", "Lake Red" => "1", "Tree" => "1" );
$array1_str = implode(" ", array_keys($array1));
$word = "Lake";
if (strpos(strtolower($array1_str), strtolower($word)) !== false) {
    print "This word is in the array.\n\n";
}
```